# Reword the Help Center article on self-answering to avoid encouraging users to edit self-answers into questions

Tags: feature-request, help-center, self-answer

There is a statement in this [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Help Center article that says:

> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time.

This statement is rather vague and upon first reading makes it sound like it may be acceptable to edit the question itself to add the answer *in the body of the question*.

[This is the Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994491/iterate-through-alphabet-in-ruby-until-x) that triggered my question.

During a relatively short span of time (minutes) the following occurred:

- I saw the question, formulated an answer, took the time to type an answer up, and then posted what I thought was a good solution.
- While I was typing up my response and testing it for accuracy, the original poster and another user had some back and forth in the comments that apparently led
  to the same general solution I had attempted to spell out.
- The original poster edited their question to both include the answer and to give credit to various parties largely negating the time I spent formulating, testing, and writing up a response and making the Q&A rather confusing (I had to go back and edit my answer due to information added during the aforementioned edit.)

I think adding information to the question body like that, especially actual answers is in extremely poor taste and greatly devalues the time people might have put into properly posting an answer. I feel like it could quickly make a mess of the Stack Overflow Q&A format and should be discouraged.

My proposal is this:

A statement should be added to the effect of "You should not edit your Question text to include an answer. If comments or answers lead you to a solution you would like to share, you should post your findings as an actual Answer."

Comment: Side note: I don't think you really need link to the question to explain this well-known problem. Linking the question that should be downvoted and closed as unclear due to lack of the question not going to make people involved happier... Rollback of the edit could be an option but OP in  that case made it much harder by combining some sort of edit of the question and adding an answer...

Comment: Somewhat related: [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) and *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*.

Comment: There's some confusion here. No, adding an answer *within* the question is not appropriate. However, posting (i.e. adding) an answer *to* the question is encouraged. Any user with edit privileges should just roll back edits which add an answer within a question and leave a polite comment explaining that answers don't belong in questions, but they are encouraged to post an actual answer as an answer post on the question. I've already done that on the question linked in this meta question.

Comment: However, I do agree that the Help Center article which you've linked doesn't make it clear that "add an answer" means *posting* an answer to the question, not adding an answer within the question. That Help Center article was written with the *implicit* understanding that "answer" often means "*post* an answer post to the question", rather than mean the text which represents an answer. If this question was written more directly about that confusion and ways to resolve it as a [feature-request], it would be a reasonable one to [tag:status-review].

Comment: I took it upon myself to edit the question to make it a proper feature request to edit the Help Center - feel free to override if it changes too much of the original intent, but I tried to tread carefully. cc @Makyen

Comment: @Oleg Valter That looks great.  Thanks so much for taking the time :)

Comment: @MichaelB Please note that adding this to the help center won't really prevent people from doing this, as users won't really go to the help center themselves. I think this should also be shown when the author is editing their question.

Comment: @Example person Good point.  At least adding it to the help center would give some guidance that could be referenced and would provide for some more explicit guidelines that could be considered for upvotes, downvotes, closings, etc.

Comment: @Exampleperson sure, something like a notification would be better, but... that's outside of our control. Any feature request that requires dev time, especially made on MSO, is basically dead on arrival (you might want to see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415778/11407695) for a broader picture) - let's focus on what we actually *can* do for those who do read the HC (there are actually more of those than you might think - the OP is a live example)

Comment: @MichaelB NP - the only thing left now is to get somebody to slap a [tag:status-review] on this and then act according to the procedure - thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that just changing [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) from:

> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> [To encourage people to do this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time.
>
> You can also [accept your own answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

to [You should be able to just copy and paste the following rendered text to get the Markdown: bold added to indicate changes, but should not be included in the actual Help Center text; Markdown links rendered as text in order to make copy and paste easier]:

> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to **post an** answer **to** their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> [To encourage people to do this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and **post** an answer to your own question at any time.
>
> You can also [accept your own answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

would be sufficient to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Agreed, but maybe let's go a step further and also remind folks that the post should actually be good? Something like "If you do, remember to follow the guidelines on how to write a good answer [link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer here]" (or something like that)

Comment: This is a better idea than mine.